# Fetch set of records in sequence until n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had a table with almost 1.7M rows. I have to fetch a set of 100 rows and perform a operation and once the first set of 100 completed, I've do the similar operation for the rows from 101 to 200. In this similar note, I've to do the operation for all the rows in the table. I do have a column with `Rownumber` as well. What will be the best approach to accomplish it?

Comment: What is the operation?

Comment: @Tim I'm concatenating few columns and deriving a new column

Comment: Can you add sample data here?  For the purpose of example, maybe just show groups of 3 records (instead of 100).

Comment: Kind of `string_agg(..) .. group by Rownumber/100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem in SSIS Package, and I solved it like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT, @RowsLimit INT, @Count INT

SET @i = 1
SET @RowsLimit = 100

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM yourTable

WHILE @i < (@Count / @RowsLimit) --Or you can hardcode @i < 17000
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable
    OFFSET (@RowsLimit * (@i - 1)) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @RowsLimit ROWS ONLY

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

In `while` you can place your logic.